# CSS rule not working

Tags: css, joomla

I am trying to apply the folowing css rule

```
div#ja-navhelper.wrap {
    display: none !important; 
}
```

to the following joomla site

http://nuevas-tecnologias.org/index.php

but it is not working

any idea why?

Comment: For a start you don't need the div in front of the #. ID selectors are unique.

Comment: Excatly, #ja-navhelper.wrap {}

Comment: @SpaceBeers not exactly true! It matters in terms of specificity!

Comment: try using `#ja-navhelper { display: none !important; }` instead

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to do this `div#idofelement`. It is better to just do this: `#idofelement`

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: And it could matter (especially when overriding several unknown css) in terms of specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're actually setting it? Because I'm not seeing it anywhere in your CSS for the website when I check using Developer Tools. However, you do have an empty `#ja-navhelper{}` and if I simply set `display:none;` inside it via Developer Tools... it works!